# Background colour of child indicator in QTreeWidgetItem?

Tags: qt, qt5, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I'm using a QTreeWidget to show a list of categorized properties.  I would like the top level items to be a different background colour; however, the arrow indicating it has children is always the default black on white (Windows 8.1, Qt 5.2.1).  Here's how I'm adding the QTreeWidget Item:

```
QBrush fg(Qt::white);
QBrush bg(Qt::darkGray);
QTreeWidgetItem *header = new QTreeWidgetItem();
header->setText(0, "Sound File");
this->addTopLevelItem(header);
header->setFirstColumnSpanned(true);
header->setData(0, Qt::ForegroundRole, fg);
header->setData(0, Qt::BackgroundRole, bg);
header->setExpanded(true);
```

Here's a screenshot of how this gets rendered.

[image: Example screenshot of my issue.]

How can I give it a solid background across the *whole* row?

Comment: i think the 'expand indicator' is an separated object and not directly linked with your `QTreeWidgetItem` but it is set from the containing `QTreeWidget`

Comment: Zaiborg, that makes sense but I can't find any properties of QTreeWidget or QTreeView that would satisfy me styling the indicator widget. I must be missing something.

Comment: maybe its deeper inside like in the used `QStyle`. but to be honest, with this problem i have no clue where to start searching

Answer (score 2):

For the indicators you can use StyleSheets something like this:

QTreeWidget::branch::!has-children:selected {background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);}
QTreeWidget::branch::!has-children:selected:alternate {background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);}

and set this StyleSheet to the QTreeWidget..

If someone knows any other way to do this for the individual items feel free to share... I have similar situation where I was one of the item that have children to be different color..